# How to deploy my application with Excel Export feature?

Tags: asp.net, excel, interop, export

I have made an `ASP.Net` application which use excel reference (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,             Version=12.0.0.0`) to export file in `.xls` format. It is working fine if the hosting server have MS Office installed.

My problem is that, I want to deploy my application without installing complete MS Office on the hosting server. I want to just copy some Dlls in my bin folder to resolve the dependencies.

I get this error when I deploy my application on the server where MS Office is not pre-installed.

> Error:   Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there anyone who have faced this problem and found some work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must install Office to use the interop libraries.  See here for more information from [Using Microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll without installing Office](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/afe35d78-ec74-457f-b8f0-d8c36d02c250)

Comment: It means, I have to install MS Office or Excel to use Interop feature in my application. Is is possible to use only few dlls and thats all?

Comment: If you're just using Excel, you can just install Excel and not the entire Office suite.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger According to MS Interop is not supported in ASP.NET etc.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger that link is only for development purposes and allows to reference the DLL in VS and build the project... BUT the question is about runtime i.e. running the application without having to install Office on the server!

Comment: @Yahia, I understand the question, and I understand that the interop libraries are not recommended for use in ASP.NET applications.  The question was whether you can install the interops without installing Office, and the answer is "No", you have to install Office (in development or in production) for it to work.  He didn't ask for alternatives to using Excel, which is what you answered, but I do agree that there are better alternatives out there.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger the OP did ask for "some work arounds". Since there are no alternatives to using Interop other than installing Office/Excel than it stands to reason that the "work around" is to use a different library that can still export to Excel format. We're not suggesting that he not use  Excel format (XLS / XLSX) but we are suggesting that he use a library that supports those format which is a work around to needing Excel installed to export to Excel files.

Answer (score 2):

*[Using Interop in Server scenarions (like ASP.NET) might technichally work sometimes BUT is NOT supported by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)*

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc. to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have used EPPlus in the past for working with Excel files:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It will support Excel 2007 and 2011 without having Excel installed. Supports both reading data from Excel as well as writing data out to Excel. Comes with some good examples.